# I cannot place an image by means of CSS in a HTML page

Tags: html, css

I have a site(place) of chat and meet a problem, precise to put an external image to the right(straight) side of some nicks. I am not expert in CSS and do not find the form. The HTML code cannot be modified since it(he,she) is of a third party that does not allow it, but if I can use rules CSS but do not find the form. If someone can help me I will be grateful for it.

Only I want to add an image to the right some name and to be able to change the color of this name especially

I leave the HTML code

```html
<div class="chatUsersTab active scrolled" tabindex="0">
  <div class="chatUsersContainer">
    <div class="chatUsers">
      <ul>
        <li class="male vip active">
          <span class="nickIcon" title="VIP">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div class="">
            <a href="#" class="nick" style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(51, 102, 255);">NiFúNiFá®</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div class="">
            <a href="#" class="nick">ACá NADIE LABURA</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div class="">
            <a href="#" class="nick">pitufo</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="male">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="nick" style="color: rgb(0, 204, 204);">German-78</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="nick">yo</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="nick">solo leo</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="away female">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="nick" style="color: rgb(51, 204, 255);">Angy</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="female">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="nick" style="color: rgb(204, 51, 204);">cabezon-</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="away male">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="nick" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 102);">Search_</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="male">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="nick" style="color: rgb(0, 153, 0);">h prince</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="nick">Μaguila</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <span class="nickIcon">
            <span class="filler">
              <span class="mask">
                <span class="status">
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="nick">Lily</a>
            <i class="groupIcon"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="chatUsersScrollBar" style="visibility: inherit;"><div style="height: 22px; top: 0px;">   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you post the code or snippets along with your attempts to solve it rather than a link. Thanks.

Comment: providing your code in the question would really help. I invite you to update your question adding your `HTML` code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to edit the html code it is not possible to insert images because they are handled by the html. You would need `<img src="img.url" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">`in your HTML document. With css you can only control the styling, the size, the opacity..... but you cant force the browser to render an image.

To change the text color normally you would do:

```
.className {
    color: blue;
}
```

But in your HTML Code there is already some styling applied so maybe your self defined color rule is overwritten (i am not sure) but you can add an `!important` statement so it will look like this

```
color : blue !important;
```

Hope it helped ;)